# my phone is not booting or cant access to recoverymode

Tags: rooting

I tried to root myGT- i8262 with many apps but it didnt worked and i tried using Odin,after i added TWRP it showed pass in odin window and when my phone was booting it showed a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark,so retried the procedure about 3-4 times and still it was not gone and i couldnt enter my recovery mode,and after searching internet i saw to recover from soft brick use recovery.tar using odin,i done that also and bow my phone doesnt starts ,when i hold the power button it showa samsung name with yellow triangle and screen turns off.please help me.

Comment: I know it happened to me

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install SamsungUSB drivers, if not already present.
2. Download and extract Odin zip file.
3. Download and extract [ROMfile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I8262/). You will either get multiple .tar.md5
   or .tar files. Launch Odin Odin3 v3.07.exe asAdministrator.
4. Click on PDA button and browse file with PDA in its name (if there
   is only one .tar/tar.md5 file then it is PDA).Click on Phone
   buttonand browse file withMODEM in its name (Ignore if not
   present).Click on CSC button and browse file with CSC in its name
   (Ignore if not present).Click on BootLoader button and browse file
   with BOOT in its name (Ignore if not present).
5. Make sure that only Auto Reboot and F. Reset time arechecked. Also
   make sure thatRe-partition check box is unchecked.
6. Switch off and power your device into Downloading modeby pressing
   and holdingVolume Down + Home + Power button and releasing only when
   you see a Warning! screen. Then press Volume up button to finally
   entering in downloading mode.
7. Plug in your device into PC using USB cable. If Odin detects your
   device the ID:COM box will turn into light blue or green. If not,
   then try reinstalling your device drivers or plug it into a
   different USB port.
8. Once every step mentioned above is successfully completed,
   press Start to begin the flashing procedure. **DON’T TRY TO INTERRUPT
   FLASHING PROCEDURE ANYHOW OTHERWISE YOUR DEVICE WILL BE HARD
   BRICKED.**  Flashing process takes time, so be patient.
9. Once flashing process is successfully completed, Odin will
   show PASS. Your device will reboot to 4.1.2, first boot is always
   very long so have patience.